# Start Varnish with a config file

Tags: varnish

**Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS**

```
varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-6.4.0 revision 13f137934ec1cf14af66baf7896311115ee35598)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2020 Varnish Software AS
```

My very first steps with studying Varnish and I've bitten the dust.

I've prepared a configuration file at **/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service**

I'm trying to start varnishd with this config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Varnish HTTP accelerator
Documentation=https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/ man:varnishd

[Service]
Type=simple
LimitNOFILE=131072
LimitMEMLOCK=82000
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -j unix,user=vcache -F -a :6081 -b :8000 -T localh$
ExecReload=/usr/share/varnish/varnishreload
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
PrivateTmp=true
PrivateDevices=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The content of the file is taken from the book "Getting started with Varnish Cache", but it is for version 4.1.

Documentation: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.4/users-guide/run_security.html#cli-interface-authentication

Well, I've prepared the file. I enter the command:

```
varnishd -S /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service
Error: Neither -b nor -f given. (use -f '' to override)
(-? gives usage)
```

But this command works fine:

```
sudo varnishd -a localhost:6081 -b localhost:8000
```

Could you help me understand:

1. What a simplest config file shoud be like.
2. Where it should be placed.
3. How to start Varnish with this config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of *Getting started with Varnish Cache*. Thanks for buying my book.

The `varnish.service` file is a `systemd` file. It has nothing to do with Varnish itself, but it's what Ubuntu uses to manage the Varnish service.

## The `ExecStart` command

Here how I would set the `ExecStart` command in `varnish.service`:

```
/usr/sbin/varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -a http=:80,HTTP -a proxy=:8443,PROXY -s malloc,1G -S /etc/varnish/secret -T localhost:6082
```

**What you're not seeing in this command:**

- `-F`: the `-F` flag only makes sense if you're running the `varnishd` process in the foreground. For example in Docker. Since you'r using `systemd` to run Varnish, you can remove that parameter
- `-b`: the `-b` option is used to define your backend location. If you use `-b`, you can't use `-f`, and you'll need `-f` for your VCL configuration.

**What the options mean**

- `-f`: the location of the VCL file. Refers to `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` in this case
- `-a`: the listening address of Varnish. In this case it's *port 80* for regular HTTP and *port 8443* for connections using the *PROXY protocol*
- `-s`: the size of the cache, in this case 1GB
- `-S`: the location of the secret key file. In this case this is `/etc/varnish/secret`
- `-T`: the listening address of the *CLI*. In this case this is `localhost` on *port 6082*

## The VCL file

The VCL file that contains the location of the backend and defines the caching rules. This file is located in `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`.

This is the minimum amount of VCL code to get going:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = 8080;
}
```

This config assumes your webserver is running on the same machine, on *port 8080*.

You can extend the configuration of varnish by hooking into [the different process states of the *Varnish Finite State Machine*](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/states.html).

See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vcl.html#varnish-configuration-language to learn more about VCL.

## Activating the changes

Whenever you update `varnish.service`, you need to reload `systemd`. This is command you need:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

To activate changes in your VCL file, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl reload varnish.service
```

Good luck!

Comment: Dear Thijs Feryn, thank you for your answer. Let me think over this information.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.4/users-guide/command-line.html

More detailed here: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.4/reference/varnishd.html

A Varnish config could for example be placed here: /etc/varnish/default.vcl

Most simple VCL:

```
backend default {
        .host = "localhost:81";
}
```

How to write VCL: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.4/users-guide/vcl.html

Comment: In the book there are both a config file and a VCL file. Could you tell me whether there is no config file any more?

Comment: I do not know of any varnish config file. Varnishd is configured via options. And then you usually have a VCL file with logic (which configured with '-f' on varnishd). If you do not need any logic you use -b on varnishd to set one backend. What other kind of config do you have in mind?

Comment: Kristian Lyngstøl also started to work on a book which got never finished but you still might want to take a look - there are five chapters: https://github.com/KristianLyng/varnishfoo

Comment: Dear Ronald, could you tell me why Varnish is that strange a technology. I mean official tutorial is about version 4.1 whereas current release is 6.4. Community is not active. The book you mentioned is not finished. There is an impression that the technology is dying. Could you tell me whether there is a more popular alternative to Varnish?

Comment: I think Varnish is great and would always choose to go with it.
The stuff written for Varnish 4.1 should still be mostly valid for 6.4. 
It is actively developed and there is a release every half year.